# Why Google Chrome browser change my IP?

Tags: google-chrome

When i browse sites google suggest to me to change language of google search page to Romanians,I disable all of my google extensions and tools but problem still exists.
how can i see hidden proxies or any malicious activities over browser?

***My OS is Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: What country are you actually in right now, and how do you connect to the internet (is your ISP also an ISP in Romania who uses dynamic IPs? Do you use a proxy or a VPN? Do you visit a lot of Romanian sites?)?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you visit the same web pages in firefox / iceweasel? When you visit [this page](https://www.whatismyip.com/) in firefox v. chrome, do you get the same answer?

Comment: @ParthianShot,I am from Iran,And using local ISP and actually ISP is in Iran right now.Also I using tor proxy but tor settings not set as default proxy in chrome,And Yes Firefox show my IP/Location in Romaina

Comment: So we know that the problem isn't with Chrome, because it's cross-browser. Which means it's more likely an issue with your machine's operating system / networking library, an issue with your router, or an inaccuracy in the GeoIP tables used to determine your location. Is this a new issue? Are there other machines on the LAN, and do they have the same problem?

Comment: No, I am not in LAN.It's seems something are wrong but how can i analyze outputs and network stack activities to get problem ? Thank you

Comment: Wait, your machine is directly connected to the internet? No router between you and your ISP? One easy thing to do would be to run [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and visit Google, then verify that your machine is generating DNS queries for Google, and sending its HTTP(S) traffic to one of the IPs it got in the A record response from the DNS query.

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge Google Chrome actually uses the proxy settings from Ubuntu, so does Firefox. Check that you don't have any proxysettings set in Ubuntu:

- Go to the Network application
- Click on Networkproxy
- Set method to none
- Press Apply settings to the whole system

Not sure if the names are correct, but it should not be hard to find.

Another easy way to debug this is to use another IP from the tor network, if the IP revealed to websites changes then you know you are on the Tor network.

You can find sites to check your IP with by using google or by using this site: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

If you are in fact not using a proxy then it might just be an GeoIP error.

Comment: As i answered to @Parthian Shot Questions, I trying to check my IP/Location with Firefox and get same result as Google chrome, So I think some things are wrong in my computer, Is possible my computer infected by some malicious or Rootkits (something like that..) or no ? how can i fix GeoIP error ?

Comment: @Farhad Well, it's possible you have malware or some kind of rootkit. It's also possible that you're using a dynamic IP, and your ISP just changed your IP to an IP that has an incorrect GeoIP listing. Unfortunately, the GeoIP listing is not something you can fix; it's a problem with the server you're accessing, not with your computer. On the bright side, if it's GeoIP, it's not a security issue; just annoying. And it may well fix itself the next time your ISP assigns you a new IP.

Comment: @Farhad The easiest least-technical way to check would be to simply call your ISP, ask them what IP they currently have assigned to you, and check that it matches the IP you get when you connect to that "whatismyip" site I linked you to earlier.

Comment: @Farhad As I said, chrome gets it's proxy settings from Ubuntu, so does Firefox. If you don't know how to get another IP in the tor network then you can just use your phone or another computer on the same network to check if that device has the same public IP.